# HoverIntent jQuery and calling the jQuery script

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

I'm working to integrate hoverintent jQuery into my site. I've plugged it into my code but I'm receiving an error from the Chrome debugger. The error reads `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use in operator to search for display in undefined`. I'm not sure what is wrong. Here is my code.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js">  

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cherne.net/brian/resources

/jquery.hoverIntent.js"></script>

</script> 

<script type="text/javascript" >

$(document).ready(function() {

var config = {    

  sensitivity: 3,
  interval: 200,   
  over: $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 500), 
  timeout: 500, 
  out: $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, 500) 

};

var config_1 = {    

  sensitivity: 3, 
  interval: 200,    
  over: $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 500),
  timeout: 500,    
  out: $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, 500) 

};


$('#form1').hoverIntent(config);

$('#form2').hoverIntent(config_1);

});

</script>
```

Here is the html code

```
<div id="div1">

<form action="" id="form1" method="post">

<textarea id="inputbox1"  name="what_i_do" maxlength="160" value=""><?php echo   

$profile_data['what_i_do']; ?></textarea>

<input type="submit" id="button1" value="Edit">

</form>

</div>

<div id="div2">

<form action="" id="form2" method="post">

<textarea id="inputbox2" name="fait_accompli"  maxlength="160" value=""><?php echo 

$profile_data['fait_accompli']; ?></textarea>

<input type="submit" id="button2" value="Edit">

</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are missing the closing curly brace and parentheses for the `document.ready` function

```
$('#form1').hoverIntent(config);

$('#form2').hoverIntent(config_1);
}); // <-----  here to close the document.ready function
```

change your configurations to include function()

```
var config = {       
  sensitivity: 3,
  interval: 200,   
  over: function(){
         $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 500)
  }, 
  timeout: 500, 
  out: function(){
         $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, 500)
  }    
};
```

Also if both configs are the same you can just remove one of them

Comment: Hmmm now I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'display' in undefined`.

Comment: Made the switch with the script imports but still getting the Uncaught TypeError.

Comment: @jason328 yeah guess hoverintent isn't dependant on jQuerUI..  I just assumed it was..  Does it show what line/file that error is occuring in?

Comment: On jquery-latest.js:6353 line

Comment: Put it up there. If you need anything else let me know.

Comment: @jason328  Found your issue.. You were missing the function call for your mouse out and over